# AWS CDK apply path to lambda role created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I'm using AWS CDK (node js) to create a lambda function. Below is the definition of my function:

```
const receiverFunction = new lambda.Function(this, "Receiver", {
      description: 'Lambda function responsible for receiving the audit message',
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("application"),
      handler: "receiver.handler",
      environment: {. . .},
      timeout: core.Duration.seconds(15),
      logRetention: logs.RetentionDays.ONE_YEAR
    });

// Define a audit queue where the messages will be published
const auditQueue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'audit-queue', {
  queueName: 'audit-queue'
});


auditQueue.grantSendMessages(receiverFunction);
```

This creates a lambda an SQS including a lambda role granting permissions to put a message in SQS. Works well with the required permissions for creating this stack.

I'm using --role-arn parameter which takes a CFN deployment role as an input. For security measures, this role is allowed to create the IAM roles with the path `cloudformation`. To be inline with this rule, I need an ability to add `path` to the role without needing to specify the complete role definition as `new iam.Role ...`.

Is there any way by which I can fetch the created lambda role above and add `path` to it?

Comment: You can use static method in Role construct roleFromArn to import existing role. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.Role.html#static-fromwbrrolewbrarnscope-id-rolearn-options

Comment: @PankajYadav I don't have a role already created. Above lambda definition will automatically create one. I would like to just add `path` variable to it's definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As lambda role is created inside Function construct. We can use [cdk escape hatches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html) to set the path.

You can use below code to set `path` or any other variable.

```
const role = receiverFunction.node.children.find(child => child instanceof Role) as Role
const cfnRole = role.node.defaultChild  as CfnRole
cfnRole.path = "/cloudformation/"
```